# How to override errors in phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I build restful api (json) on phoenix. And I did not need the support of html.

How to override errors in phoenix? Example errors:
- 500
- 404 when no route found
and other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to customize `MyApp.ErrorView`. Phoenix generates this file for you in web/views/error_view.ex. The default content of the template can be found [on Github](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/666350bc18a7bf3b055e6fe1a7e145614ab5baf5/priv/template/web/views/error_view.ex).

Also see [the docs on custom errors](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/views.html#the-errorview), although they seem to be a bit outdated because they instruct you to use `MyApp.ErrorsView` (plural), which was replaced with `MyApp.ErrorView`

Comment: Yes, I saw it. But not work for me, maybe I'm doing something wrong. Example - https://gist.github.com/saa/c175ae731e32790de17f

Comment: This answer is correct. Unfortunately there is a bug in the error handling that is avoiding the custom errors to trigger. If you move temporarily `plug :accepts, ...` from your router to the endpoint, it may work. Otherwise please wait for a new Phoenix release.

Comment: How to correctly specify this in endpoint? If just - plug :accepts, ~w(json) I have error function accepts/2 undefined.

Comment: The link for custom errors is dead, the actual link is this [one](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/views.html#the-errorview)

Comment: Thanks @EdouardMenayde, I fixed it!

Answer (score 8):

For those who may have the same issues I had, there a couple of steps required to render JSON for 404 and 500 responses.

Firstly add `render("404.json", _assigns)` and `render("500.json", _assigns)` to your app's `web/views/error_view.ex` file.

For example:

```
defmodule MyApp.ErrorView do
  use MyApp.Web, :view

  def render("404.json", _assigns) do
    %{errors: %{message: "Not Found"}}
  end

  def render("500.json", _assigns) do
    %{errors: %{message: "Server Error"}}
  end
end
```

Then in your `config/config.exs` file updated the `default_format` to `"json"`.

```
config :my_app, MyApp.Endpoint,
  render_errors: [default_format: "json"]
```

Note that if your app is purely a REST api this will be fine, but be careful in the event you also render HTML responses as now by default errors will be rendered as json.

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted. This answer works for me and the accepted answer doesn't. Instead of modifying default_format I modified 'accepts' by removing the html value.

Answer (score 1):

None of the answer above worked for me.
The only way i was able to make phoenix use `json` only for the api endpoint was to edit the endpoint settings this way :

```ex
config :app, App.Endpoint,
       render_errors: [
         view: App.ErrorView,
         accepts: ~w(json html) # json has to be in before html otherwise only html will be used
       ]
```

The idea being json has to be the first of the world list for html to be rendered, kinda weird but it works.

Then have an ErrorView which looks like this :

```ex
defmodule App.ErrorView do
  use App, :view

  def render("400.json", _assigns) do
    %{errors: %{message: "Bad request"}}
  end

  def render("404.json", _assigns) do
    %{errors: %{message: "Not Found"}}
  end

  def render("500.json", _assigns) do
    %{errors: %{message: "Server Error"}}
  end
end
```

Nothing different from the other answer here, I just added a 400 bad request because I ran into it and you should too : add anything that you might run into.

And finally in my router code:

```ex
pipeline :api do
  plug(:accepts, ["json"])
end
pipeline :browser do
  plug(:accepts, ["html"])
  ...
end
```

Nothing different from the other answer but you have to make sure your pipelines are configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can override 400-500 errors with `plug :accepts, ["json"]` in you `router.ex`. For example:

```
# config/config.exs
...
config :app, App.endpoint,
  ...
  render_errors: [accepts: ~w(html json)],
  ...    

# web/views/error_view.ex
defmodule App.ErrorView do
 use App.Web, :view

 def render("404.json", _assigns) do
   %{errors: %{message: "Not Found"}}
 end

 def render("500.json", _assigns) do
   %{errors: %{message: "Server Error"}}
 end
end


# in router.ex
defmodule App.Router do
 use App.Web, :router

 pipeline :api do
   plug :accepts, ["json"]
 end

 pipe_through :api

 # put here your routes
 post '/foo/bar'...

 # or in scope: 
 scope '/foo' do
   pipe_through :api
   get 'bar' ...
 end
```

It will works.